# What is the probability of drawing 12 marked cards?

Tags: probability, card-games

I have a deck of 40 cards. 16 of the cards are marked and the rest are unmarked. The deck is sufficiently shuffled. If I draw 12 cards off the top, what is the probability that each one would be marked?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/531230/299542 Basically that answer gives you the intuition of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

The first card drawn has a $\frac {16}{40}$ chance to be marked.

Then, you have $39$ cards, $15$ of which are marked.

The second card drawn has a $\frac{15}{39}$ chance to be marked.

The third card drawn has a $\frac{14}{38}$ chance to be marked and so on.

Therefore the probability of drawing $12$ marked cards in a row is

$$\frac{16\times15\times14\times...\times5}{40\times39\times38\times...\times29}$$

Comment: I figured it would be this. But is there a generic formula?

Comment: Well I'm not sure how generalised you want the formula, but my answer above simplfies to $\frac{16! \div 4!}{40!}$. So if you had $n$ cards, $k$ of which were marked, then the probability of drawing $r$ marked cards without replacement would be given by $\frac{k! \div (k-r)!}{n!}$.

Answer (score 1):

[Hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) gives here:$$\frac{\binom{16}{12}\binom{24}{0}}{\binom{40}{12}}$$